# Browse file from external memory and display file name on toast

Tags: java, android

In my android application I am putting `onclick` listener on Button. After click on button filemanager will open. But what i want to do is when filemanager open and I select some file then One Toast should display with selected filename and path of that file.

Can anybody tell me how to do this in my activity.

Comment: put some efforts and code first if its not working then ask on Stack Overflow

Comment: @sandeep i asked this question because i already tried a lot of    things but not working..and i need help for that

Comment: @raj i am sending my code to you have a look and suggest me something ..thanks raj

Comment: ok send me your code

Comment: Could you please show code on how are you showing the FileManager?